# Can't compare database query from flask to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a flask-based site and I query the database in Flask and send that list of values to my html page. From there I have a script that compares a variable to an element in the list, but the case never works.

```
def start():

title = ""
paragraph = ["Cognitive Motor"]

pageType = 'start'


#if request.form.get("cognitiveAbility1" != None):
methodsQuery = db.engine.execute("select method from permutations")
motorQuery = db.engine.execute("select cognitivemotor from permutations")
motorList = motorQuery.fetchall()
data = request.stream.read()
methodList = methodsQuery.fetchall()
data2 = request.stream.read()
return render_template("start.html", title=title, paragraph=paragraph, pageType=pageType,data=data, methodList=methodList,motorList=motorList)
```

That is the code in flask, and below is the script I have in my html file.
The case if the if statement never works and won't print out the console.log("test").

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '.submitButton', function cognitiveFunction() {


            var checkCog = document.getElementsByName("cognitive");
            var checkMot = document.getElementsByName("motorCheck");
            var resultCog = '';
            var resultMot = '';
            var motorQuery= "";
            for(i = 0; i <3; i++) {

                if(checkCog[i].checked === true) {
                resultCog += checkCog[i].value + '';
                console.log(resultCog);
                }   
            }
            for(i = 0; i <8; i++) {
                if(checkMot[i].checked === true) {
                    resultMot += 'Yes';
                }
                else {
                    resultMot += 'No';
                }
            }
            motorQuery = resultCog + resultMot ;

            for(i = 0; i <19; i++) {

                if ( '{{ motorList [i]}}' == motorQuery){
                    console.log('test');
                    $('body').append("{{ methodList [i] }}")
                }
            }
```

When I just print a value from the list of motorList into my html page manually, it looks like this,
(u'Cognitively intactNoNoYesNoYesNoYesYes',) 
But in the database it is just
Cognitively intactNoNoYesNoYesNoYesYes

Comment: Does this solve the issue? `return render_template("start.html", title=title, paragraph=paragraph, pageType=pageType,data=data, methodList=str(methodList),motorList=str(motorList))`

Comment: No it didnt work, thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding of how JS and Flask interact. There is no possible way to put the JS variable `i` into the Jinja template variable `'{{ motorList[i] }}`, because Jinja is rendered on the server long before the JS runs on the client.

You will need to output the entire `motorList` in a format accessible to your script, ie JSON, and then iterate through that in JS.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense now. Thank you very much!